# How to find all content in a <td> after a <th> with specific text?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Given a `table` like:

```
<tr>
    <th scope="row" style="padding-right: 1em;">Date</th>
    <td>
        April&nbsp;26, 1937
        <span class="noprint">; 80 years ago</span>
        <span style="display:none">&nbsp;(<span class="bday dtstart published updated">1937-04-26</span>)</span><br>
        16:30 – 19:30 (<a href="/wiki/Central_European_Time" title="Central European Time">CET</a>)
    </td>
</tr>
```

How to grab all dates in the `<td>` by checking all `<th>` with text ***Date***? eg. `April 26, 1937` Actually i simply need the `year`.

**Js:**

```
var url="https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=parse&disablelimitreport=true&format=json&page=" + myTitle +"&redirects&prop=text&callback=?";
$.getJSON(url,function(data){
  wikiHTML = data.parse.text["*"];
  $wikiDOM = $("<document>"+wikiHTML+"</document>");
  $("#results").append("<li>" + $wikiDOM.find('.infobox .date').html() + "</li>");
});

<ul id="results">

</ul>
```

On the above I am checking for a class `.date` but what if it is a text in a `<th>`?

JsFiddle using the class `.Location`: https://jsfiddle.net/zt3ssajd/106/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the selector [contains()](https://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/) to find all elements containing a given text. Combine with [siblings](https://api.jquery.com/siblings/) to find the td-element. Combine them together:

```
$('th:contains("Date")') // Find th with text "Date" in it
    .siblings('td')      // Get sibling td
    .find('.published')  // Find something with class 'published'
    .text().substring(0, 4) // Get first 4 charatecters of text
```

Proof of concept (enable console): https://jsfiddle.net/petervanderwal/xn73d0d2/1/

Comment: hi thanks, could you elaborate it more on the jsFiddle for any future ref and a more precise answer?

Comment: Actually i simply need the year *

Answer (score 0):

You may check :

html:

```
<h2>TABLE DATA</h2>
    <table id="testTable"> 
    <tr>
    <th scope="row" style="padding-right: 1em;">Date</th>
    <td>
        April&nbsp;26, 1937
        <span class="noprint">; 80 years ago</span>
        <span style="display:none">&nbsp;(<span class="bday dtstart published updated">1937-04-26</span>)</span><br>
        16:30 – 19:30 (<a href="/wiki/Central_European_Time" title="Central European Time">CET</a>)
    </td>
    </tr>
    </table>
    <hr />

     <h2>TARGET DATA</h2>
    <p id="showOutPut"></p
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var content=$('#testTable tr').find('th').siblings('td').html();
$('#showOutPut').html(content);
console.log('Output : '+content);
});
```

To check the output tareget or console at JSFiddle [Table Test](https://jsfiddle.net/abumuaz/4ycm5Ls9/)

**Note:** Just use .text() for your case.